# ftp_nlist return empty array even is somethink in directory

Tags: php, debian

The following line in my code is returning sometimes an empty array when in fact the given path is not empty:

```
ftp_nlist($connection, '/var/movies/'.$idcat);
```

sometimes i means, in morning everything is working okej, but in the evening everything stops working..

I suspected it depends on server load and I found something like that:

```
ftp_pasv($connection, true);
ftp_nlist($connection, '/var/movies/'.$idcat);
```

but still nlist return empty array.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this script to get the names of all the files on my ftp server. This might help you.

## Libraries

import re
import os
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP("192.168.1.201")
ftp.login("Username", "Password")

files = []

F = open('Files.txt','a')

try:
    files = ftp.nlst()
    for fname in files:
        res = re.findall("", fname)
        if res:
            print fname
            F.write(fname + '\n')
        if not res:
            continue
except ftplib.error_perm, resp:
    if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
        print "No files in this directory"
    else:
        raise

F.close()

Note: Sometimes due to huge traffic on the server or if the directory from which you want to get the files is open somewhere and it is not providing you the access...This maybe the problem in your case.